# Can secure and normal web pages be hosted in the same domain?

Tags: ssl, hosting

Can secure and normal web pages be hosted in the same domain?

My sites has
index.php
account.php
work.php

Right now all of them are accessible from http://

In future I wish **only** one of the pages "account.php" to be accessed from https://

Will that be possible?  Or will all the pages **be only accessible** from https (because of the ssl certificate installed).

Comment: You could probably get a little more specific instructions on where to start looking if you provided your OS and what web server you're running

Comment: -1 because anyone who has spent more than a few minutes on the Internet will have seen numerous examples of HTTP and HTTPS URLs from the same domains.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can choose what portion is indexed via the site map for ssl.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible (and common) to configure a web server to serve HTTP and HTTPS traffic from the same directory. You'd need to specifically protect `account.php` from being accessed over normal HTTP, likely with a redirect.